# Apex Class Error

Tags: apex, apexrest

Rest service Code:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/wrapper/*')
global with sharing class campclass{
    @HttpGet
    global static campclass  doget(){
        blob body;
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        String accphone = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;

        list<account> account1 = new list<account>();
        List<account> result = [Select Id, name,phone from account where  phone=:accphone];
        System.debug('Result:::'+result);
        body = Blob.valueOf(result);
        campclass obj = campclass.parse(body.tostring());

        return obj;
    }

    public static campclass parse(string result1){
        return (campclass)System.JSON.deserialize(result1, campclass.class);
    }

    public class Accountwrapper
    {
        Public List<account> Id;
        public List<account> Name;
        public List<account> Phone;
    }
}
```

Postman Input:

> Method:Get Method
>
> Uri:https://xxx.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/wrapper/123

It is getting two records containing phone number in salesforce and how to parse the record according to my account wrapper and return the id name and phone to postman.

while saving the apex class it is showing error like:

> Error: Compile Error: Variable does not exist: Blob

Comment: can you tell the line number where where error is getting generated ?

Comment: body = Blob.valueOf(result);

Answer (score 1):

This is because `Blob.valueOf(result)` expect [string as parameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_blob.htm) while you are passing List of Account. Thats why you are getting this error.

You can take help of `Serialization and Deserialization` to convert the list into string and then again convert it back to list.

Here is a code sample for your help.

```
    List<account> result = [Select Id, name,phone from account where phone='(907) 681-5915'];      
// Serialize the list of InvoiceStatement objects.
String JSONString = JSON.serialize(result);
System.debug('Serialized list of invoices into JSON format: ' + JSONString);

// Deserialize the list of invoices from the JSON string.
List<Account> deserializedresults = 
    (List<Account>)JSON.deserialize(JSONString, List<Account>.class);
System.assertEquals(result.size(), deserializedresults.size());
```

[Reference](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_json.htm)

Comment: It would be really good if you can provide the solution like how to convert list of account into Blob. :)

Comment: @PrabhatKumar I am updating answer. Give me 5 minute.

Comment: @cloudcomputinginsalesforce check my updated answer.

Comment: @cloudcomputinginsalesforce check my updated code. You can use `JSONString ` in blob and and in the end you can again do Deserialization

Comment: @TusharSharma in postman it is showing error like [
  {
    "errorCode": "APEX_ERROR",
    "message": "System.JSONException: Malformed JSON: Expected '{' at the beginning of object\n\nClass.System.JSON.deserialize: line 15, column 1\nClass.campclass.parse: line 18, column 1\nClass.campclass.doget: line 14, column 1"
  }
]

Comment: @TusharSharma it is not returning id name and phone

Comment: @TusharSharma are you there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49427/discussion-between-cloud-computing-in-salesforce-and-tushar-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

Add on to the answer. You can use below code, it will not throw any error while saving.

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/wrapper/*')
global with sharing class campclass{
@HttpGet
global static campclass  doget(){
blob body;
RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
String accphone = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
list<account> account1 = new list<account>();
List<account> result = [Select Id, name,phone from account where  phone=:accphone];
System.debug('Result:::'+result);
string str = JSON.serialize(result);
body = Blob.valueOf(str);
campclass obj = campclass.parse(body.tostring());
return obj;
}
public static campclass parse(string result1){
return (campclass)System.JSON.deserialize(result1, campclass.class);
}

public class Accountwrapper
{
Public List<account> Id;
public List<account> Name;
public List<account> Phone;
}
}
```